# Connecting to Microsoft Analysis Server using SSIS Import/Export-Assistant

Tags: ssis, connection, mdx

Goal is to export Data from a Microsoft Analysis Server Cube into a flatfile in a lean way.

I use the SQL Server-Import/Export-Assistant.
Using the option *"Copy data from one or more tables or views*" the download runs smoothly. -> **No problems**

When I use an MDX expression ("*Write a query to specify the data to transfer*") query pre-executing it gives an **error message**

> *Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.*

**Edit**: Please note that I try to run the *SQL Server 2016 RC0 Import and Export Data* Wizard -> Must use this one as it is the only valid licence.

**Edit**:
I recognized differences in the following MDX expressions.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT
  [Measures].[measure1] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
  [order].[orderid].[orderid].AllMembers
* [order_spec].[spec].[spec].AllMembers ON ROWS
FROM [cube];
```

1. SQL Server 2014 Management Studio: **works**
2. SQL Server Import and Export Data Wizard: **Error 0x80040E21**
3. Visual Studio 2015, Data Flow Task: Error **0x80040E21**

**Query 2**

```
SELECT * FROM 
[cube].[cube_tab].[$spec2]
```

1. SQL Server 2014 Management Studio: **works**
2. SQL Server Import and Export Data Wizard: **works**
3. Visual Studio 2015, Data Flow Task: **works**

Also note, that when I use the option "*Copy data from one or more tables or views*" I cannot choose any measures.

Also I am not able to set up any openquery procedure using the Wizard.

Comment: Is it  tabular model or a multidimensional?

Comment: Its a multidimensional OLAP cube

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have SQL-server

Create a linked server to the cube database

You can then write an mdx query inside a tsql query like described here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa936673(v=sql.80).aspx

I used scripts in the form of the last snippet in the above reference:

```
select * from openquery 
( LINKED_OLAP, 'select { measures.[unit sales] } on columns,
 non empty nest( nest( [customer location].[country].members, 
[gender].members ), [product category].[bread].children ) on rows 
from sales ')
```

If the above looks like a possibility then I would strongly suggest going straight to the following - it is a wonderful stored procedure:

https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/

---

**Edit**

This isn't standard mdx:

```
SELECT
  {[Measures].[measure1]} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME]
   ,[MEMBER_CAPTION] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
  CROSSJOIN(
    [order].[orderid].[orderid].AllMembers,
    [order_spec].[spec].[spec].AllMembers
  )
DIMENSION PROPERTIES
    [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME]
   ,[MEMBER_CAPTION] ON ROWS
FROM [cube]
```

This is a lot simpler:

```
SELECT
  [Measures].[measure1] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
     [order].[orderid].[orderid].AllMembers,
   * [order_spec].[spec].[spec].AllMembers
  ON ROWS
FROM [cube];
```

Maybe this is also sufficient:

```
SELECT
  [Measures].[measure1] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
     [order].[orderid].[orderid].MEMBERS,
   * [order_spec].[spec].[spec].MEMBERS
  ON ROWS
FROM [cube];
```

Comment: Using the SQL Server Import/Export Wizard (tried 2008, 2014).

Now getting the error message:
**Query (1, 15) Parser: The syntax for 'Openquery' is incorrect.**

Comment: Addition: Running the MDX query under 2014 SQL Server Management Studio works fine -> problem is to write the results directly to a flatfile as the data is large and needs to be processed in R Studio or SPSS

Comment: did you read the article on how to use Openquery? You need to first set up a working linked server (in sql-server) - give the linked server a name and then replace `LINKED_OLAP` in the above with the name of your linked server. You can write the data to disk in sql server then move it into R-Studio using r's sql package

Comment: Can that be done before the query in the wizard like this:

`EXEC sp_dropserver 'LINKED_OLAP'
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
     @server='LINKED_OLAP',  
     @srvproduct='', 
     @provider='MSOLAP',
     @datasrc='xx.xx:51003', 
     @catalog='cube_name' 

   
EXEC sp_tables_ex
   @table_server='cube_name'

EXEC sp_columns_ex 
   @table_server='LINKED_OLAP',
   @table_name='cube_name'



Select * from openquery (LINKED_OLAP, 'SELECT xxx')`

Gives me the error **Parser: The syntax for 'sp_dropserver' is incorrect**

Comment: BTW: I only have reading rights on the OLAP server and is setting up a server just to query the Cube and write the results into a flatfile a bit over-engineered? -> Also wondering why it is running smoothely when I just select "Copy data from one or more table views"....what is the difference between the connection of that and the one querying with MDX?

Comment: I don't think "linked servers" in ssms are so complex - our dba could add them in a couple of - a linked server involves no hardware - it just cretaes a bridge between the sql-server and ssas server

Comment: This option is better: https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/. We do not use OPENQUERY anymore - we only use the this stored procedure.

Comment: Adding a server is due to our complex policies no option. OLAPEXTENSIONS are used for T-SQL queries and not for MDX queries in my opinion. I only have access to a Microsoft Analysis Services Cube. I also tried my query via a Visual Studio Data Flow task getting the same error message: **Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.**

Comment: OLAPEXTENSIONS  is to move results from olap into ssms.

Comment: Cannot get it running using the *Import and Export Wizard*